# How do I share (model) data with the layout view and partials in the layout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a partial view(strongly typed)a1 defined within my Master Layout view(A). I then have a sub view(B) who itself is a layout view but nested within the Master Layout view. Then I have a page view from which is invoked and loaded with model data. How do I pass data within this data up to the Partial view nested in the Master Layout view please?

Shared/_Layout.cshtml (Master Layout)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
           @RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/PartialViews/Shared/_headerView.cshtml")
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Shared/_Layout.cshtml (SubLayout)

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Blog";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@if (IsSectionDefined("BlogHeaderContent"))
{
    <div class="blogHeader">
        @RenderSection("BlogHeaderContent", required: false)
    </div>
}
    @RenderBody()
```

Views/Blogs/blogindex.cshtml (Blog View)

```
@model MyModels.Blog
@{
    ViewBag.Title = " See Blog";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Blog</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Body)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Body)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Body)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: You should post sample code.

Comment: Why is your Master and Sub Layouts the same file (Shared/_Layout.cshtml)?

Comment: It would probably be good to have _all_ the code or fix up what you put in the ? because it looks like 3 completely unrelated views.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of options:

First, I feel it's kinda of hacky, but you could populate a property the ViewData/ViewBag.  It's hacky (in my opinion) because it's not strongly typed, you don't know what object would be put in there.

Secondly, still a little hacky, you could have your layout and partial have a (strongly?) typed model of Object.  They attempt to check and see if it has the data you are looking for (via reflection or an interface).

Thirdly, less hacky but really restrictive, you can create an interface that all your view models have to derive from, then your Layout and Layout Partial can use that for a Model.  The problem becomes any other developer who doesn't know that your view models need to derive from a specific interface will blow up the app.

Last, probably the best solution, (assuming that your layout-partial doesn't care what is executing), create a controller with an [ChildOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.childactiononlyattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) attribute (*Any method that is marked with ChildActionOnlyAttribute can be called only with the Action or RenderAction HTML extension methods.*).  This is the best because it implements the [Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).  The Sublayout doesn't care what view is executing and the view knows nothing about whats happening in the layout.

```
public class LayoutController
{
  [ChildOnly]
  public ActionResult SubLayout()
  {
    // Get Some Model Data
    var SubLayoutViewModel model = new SubLayoutViewModel();
    return this.View(model)
  }
}
```

Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      @Html.RenderAction("Layout", "SubLayout")
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

SubLayout.cshtml

```
@model SubLayoutViewModel

@Model.SomeData.ToString() // or whatever

@if (IsSectionDefined("BlogHeaderContent"))
{
  <div class="blogHeader">
    @RenderSection("BlogHeaderContent", required: false)
  </div>
}

@RenderBody()
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy the data from your strongly-typed model to the `ViewBag` similarly to how the title is being set in the `ViewBag` in your view:

```
ViewBag.Title = "See Blog";
```

You can put other data in there, then access it later in your layout and partial views.